Effect of the input pipe blinking on all tags in MAUI with WebView
this is an interesting problem regarding MAUI, and I have not found any solutions so far.
The problem is the following, I am using an iframe to render a web page within MAUI, it shows a blinking pipe (the same as the text input ones, when they have focus), in all tags within the iframe (this behavior only happens when I click somewhere on the site).
And when I say iframe, I'm talking about two solutions, the html iframe tag using MAUI's blazor, and the MAUI native xaml's WebView tag.
Tests are being done using Windows and .NET 8.
MainPage.xaml
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SafeguardLauncher"
             x:Class="SafeguardLauncher.MainPage">

    <WebView Source="http://127.0.0.1:5173/login" />

</ContentPage>

Platforms/Windows/App.xaml
<maui:MauiWinUIApplication
    x:Class="SafeguardLauncher.WinUI.App"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:maui="using:Microsoft.Maui"
    xmlns:local="using:SafeguardLauncher.WinUI">

    <Application.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="MauiAppTitleBarTemplate">
            <Grid Background="#850505" Canvas.ZIndex="1" Height="32" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="32" />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Margin="5,0,0,0" Source="soundscapes_icon.png" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Sound Scapes" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5,0,0,0" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Application.Resources>
</maui:MauiWinUIApplication>

MauiProgram.cs
.UseMauiApp<App>()
.ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
{
    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
});

builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();

#if WINDOWS
builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
{
    events.AddWindows(windowsLifecycleBuilder =>
    {
        windowsLifecycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
        {
            var handle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
            var id = Microsoft.UI.Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(handle);
            var appWindow = Microsoft.UI.Windowing.AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(id);
            var titleBar = appWindow.TitleBar;
            var favoriteColor = new Windows.UI.Color()
            {
                R = 0x1C,
                G = 0x1C,
                B = 0x1C,
            };

            titleBar.BackgroundColor = favoriteColor;
            titleBar.ButtonBackgroundColor = favoriteColor;
            titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White.ToWindowsColor();
            titleBar.InactiveBackgroundColor = favoriteColor;
            titleBar.InactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White.ToWindowsColor();
            titleBar.ButtonInactiveBackgroundColor = favoriteColor;
            titleBar.ButtonInactiveForegroundColor = Colors.White.ToWindowsColor();
            titleBar.ButtonForegroundColor = Colors.White.ToWindowsColor();
            titleBar.ButtonPressedBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGray.ToWindowsColor();
            titleBar.ButtonHoverBackgroundColor = Colors.DarkGray.ToWindowsColor();
        });
    });
});
#endif

The problem (pipe is in "account"):


please do NOT post code as images
